# Why does `read` return a symbol when `read-line` returns a string

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure by following the [Hackerrank 30 days of code](https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/tutorials/30-days-of-code), and lost some hours due to a behavior I neither understand nor found any documentation or explanation about:

- `(read)` returns a symbol:

  ```clj
  user=> (def key-read (read))
  sam
  #'user/key-read
  user=> (type key-read)
  clojure.lang.Symbol
  ```
- `(read-line)` returns a string

  ```clj
  user=> (def key-line (read-line))
  sam
  #'user/key-line
  user=> (type key-line)
  java.lang.String
  ```

As a result, parsing a line with `(read) (read)` to get map keys and values results in the keys to be symbols, than will never be matched by a further `(read-line)`.

Why is this so? And also, where can I find the return value? (this is not documented in `(doc read)`).

Comment: Are you asking, why `(read)` consumes the stream and a following call to `(read-line)` no longer sees the content consumed by `read`? Maybe it would be best to show your actual problem?

Comment: @cfrick no, that's not my intent. The problem is Day 8, where input is taken as words from standard input. So, I intended to use `(read) (read)` twice to parse a line with two words... but I faced that `(read)` is not what I thought it is, hence my request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL;DR

- `clojure.core/read` is used to read "code" by Clojure itself
- `clojure.edn/read` is used to read "data" (EDN)
- `read-line` is used to read text lines as string; it's your problem to
  decipher them

#### What can `read` do for you

`read` does not *only* read symbols, but anything, that Clojure uses to
represent code.  If you give it a symbol to parse, it will give you
symbol back:

```
(type (read))
test
clojure.lang.Symbol
```

But also other things

```
(type (read))
5
java.lang.Long

(type (read))
{:a 42}
clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

(type (read))
"hello"
java.lang.String
```

So you can get back a string with `read` too, if you feed it a string.

#### real-world use of `read`

Usually `read` is used by Clojure itself and that's it.  Reading
EDN is usually done using `clojure.edn/read`, which does not allow code
execution and therefor is no security risk if handling EDN from
untrusted sources.

#### docs

For good measure, here are the docs:

```
(doc read)
-------------------------
clojure.core/read
([] [stream] [stream eof-error? eof-value] [stream eof-error? eof-value recursive?] [opts stream])
  Reads the next object from stream, which must be an instance of
  java.io.PushbackReader or some derivee.  stream defaults to the
  current value of *in*.

  Opts is a persistent map with valid keys:
    :read-cond - :allow to process reader conditionals, or
                 :preserve to keep all branches
    :features - persistent set of feature keywords for reader conditionals
    :eof - on eof, return value unless :eofthrow, then throw.
           if not specified, will throw

  Note that read can execute code (controlled by *read-eval*),
  and as such should be used only with trusted sources.

  For data structure interop use clojure.edn/read

(doc read-line)
-------------------------
clojure.core/read-line
([])
  Reads the next line from stream that is the current value of *in* .
```

Comment: I read the doc from the REPL, but as there is no indication of return value/type, I really needed the first part of your answer to understand the intent; thanks!

Comment: The Clojure doc strings tend to be hyper-condensed, because they are
intended for "experts" to quickly look things up.  For beginners third
party documentation is basically a must in their first steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Clojure API documentation at https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html.  Both `read` and `read-line` are there.

Your specific goal isn't quite clear, but in general, application software prefers `read-line` and parses the results in whatever way makes sense... perhaps with `re-matches` for regular expressions.  Clojure itself reads program code with `read`.

Comment: thanks for the link! this provides much more insight about the API than what [clojure.org/reference](https://clojure.org/reference) provides.

Answer (score 1):

The other 2 answers are good. I didn't even know that `clojure.core/read` existed!

I only wanted to add in a list of [my favorite documentation sources](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation).
Please review & study the [Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet), which links to examples on [clojuredocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/).

Unfortunately, the API docs at clojure.org are not as descriptive and it is harder to find things unless you already know the name and location.